# How can I keep trailing zeros when rounding with TI-84 Plus CE?

Tags: calculator

I am trying to round the value of an expression to two decimal places while keeping any trailing zeros.  For example, I would like 36.397 to round to 36.40, not 36.4.  I have tried writing the following code, but it always removes any trailing zeros:

`Output(4,13,round(100/X,2))`

Is there any other way to round numbers using commands on a TI-84 calculator?  Any code that changes the rounding settings of the calculator from "FLOAT" to "2" would also work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering, it is possible to adjust the rounding settings of the calculator by simply using `Fix` followed by the number of decimal places to round to (in my case, `Fix 2`).  Using `Float` reverts the rounding settings to remove trailing zeros.